# Chronometer doesn't update in app widget ListView

Tags: android, listview, widget, chronometer

I have an app widget displaying timers. Timers can be started, stopped or resumed.

On Android 8  timers don't tick sometimes (50/50).  Some users complained about the issue on Android 7 but I'm not absolutely sure if it's the same issue. Everything works well on Nexus 5 with Android 6 installed. If scroll down list view (until chronometer is invisible) and scroll up - timer starts ticking. If I put one more Chronometer above ListView and start - the chronometer is ticking well

**ActivitiesRemoteViewsFactory**

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
...

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), getItemLayoutId());

    if (timeLog.getState() == TimeLog.TimeLogState.RUNNING) {          

        remoteViews.setChronometer(R.id.widget_timer,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - (duration * 1000 + System.currentTimeMillis() - timeLog.getStartDate().getTime()), null, true);
    } else {
        long timerValue = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - duration * 1000;
        remoteViews.setChronometer(R.id.widget_timer, timerValue, null, false);

    }

    return remoteViews;
```

Update is sent from **AppWidgetProvider**'s onReceive method

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
   AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(ctx);
    ...
   widgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.widget_activities_list);
}
```

TargetSDK is 25

**UPDATE** 
The issue is also reproduced in main app. Something is wrong with listView as it works well in RecyclerView. Added simple example reproducing the issue at https://github.com/zaplitny/WidgetIssue

Answer (score 10):

The `Chronometer` widget was updated between API 25 and API 26 to prevent non-visible timers from updating. (That is my best guess from looking at the underlying code.) Specifically, the `updateRunning()` method was changed to take into account whether the widget is shown or not. From `Chronometer.java`:

For API 25: `boolean running = mVisible && mStarted;`

For API 26: `boolean running = mVisible && mStarted && isShown();`

That `isShown()` is the source of your problem and it stops your `Chronometers` from being reused. For API 26+, reused `Chronometers` do not get updated, it seems, when they are in a `ListView`.

There are several ways to take care of this issue. The first is to not reuse `Chronometers`. In `getView()` of your adapters, you can use the following code:

```
if (view == null || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.widget_timer, parent, false);
}
```

With this code, you will always create new `Chronometers` and never reuse them.

An alternative to this is to call `chronometer.start()` after the widget is laid out and `isShown()` will be true. Add the following code to `getView()`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    chronometer.start();
} else {
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            chronometer.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Either way works and there are other ways.

Comment: @zaplitny IMO this is a bug in `Chronometer`. The code I presented will work around the problem.

Comment: sorry I deleted my previous comment as I missed some details in your answer. I need chronometer in AppWidget and AFAIK it's not possible with your workaround. But I may be wrong

Comment: @zaplitny The code I presented works with the test app you provided. Don't know about `AppWidget`, though. I surmise that it is the same problem. It still uses a `ListView`, right? So, a check for API 26+ to suppress the reuse of views should work.

Comment: @zaplitny I see what you mean about the `AppWidget` - the `ListView` is internal so you don't have access like in the test app. I still think that the issue has been identified. The question is how to export a fix to `AppWidget`.

Comment: Just for information, I posted the issue to Google Dev team - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74058586. Everyone interested can vote

Comment: @zaplitny Got my vote. I looked at this again, but I didn't see a work around for the widget implementation. I think that you will have this problem until the underlying issue is fixed. There is such a small keyhole view into the widget machinery.

Comment: issuetracker.google.com/issues/74058586 is marked as "Won't Fix  (Obsolete)" at Jun 27, 2019 07:38AM... Cheticamp options still working! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you application manifest :

```
 <!-- Widget Receiver -->
        <receiver android:name=".widgets.WidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
        </receiver>
```

Now when you want to update widget from application call this:

```
                  try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ctxt, WidgetProvider.class);
                        intent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
                        int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(ctxt).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(ctxt, WidgetProvider.class));
                        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
                        ctxt.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I have used this to update my widget.
Thank you.

Comment: The question is not how to update widget. Widget content is updated well but Chronometer doesn't work as expected in ListView